# Xml parsing to Java object

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have xml sth like this:

```
 <EVENTSTREAM id="2016050408105300002" name="LATESTWINNERS" rc="0">
    <ROUND id="2016050309342400001" nyxid="2016050309342400003">
    <TIMESTAMP>2016-05-03T09:34:24.000</TIMESTAMP>
    <PLAYERINFO accountid="112307829" firstname="Simon" lastname="Schork" nickname="SimonSchork" zip="76133" operatorid="275" currency="EUR" language="" country="DE" city="SimonSchork" sex="M" universe="Default"/>
    <CHANNEL>I</CHANNEL>
    <BALANCE>110.34</BALANCE>
    <WONAMOUNT>3.00</WONAMOUNT>
    <BONUSWONAMOUNT>0.00</BONUSWONAMOUNT>
    <SUBSYSTEMID>3</SUBSYSTEMID>
    <CAT1>1</CAT1>
    <CAT2>1</CAT2>
    <CAT3>30136</CAT3>
    <OUTCOME>W</OUTCOME>
    <CLIENT>flash</CLIENT>
    <BETAMOUNT>1.00</BETAMOUNT>
    <BONUSBETAMOUNT>0.00</BONUSBETAMOUNT>
    <BASECURRENCY>EUR</BASECURRENCY>
    </ROUND>
```

I created model like this, LastWinnersModel

```
@Root(name = "EVENTSTREAM", strict = false)
public class LastWinnersModel {

    @Attribute(name = "name", required = false)
    private String name;

    @Attribute(name = "rc")
    private int rc;

    @Attribute(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ElementList(name = "ROUND", entry = "ROUND", inline = true, required = false)
    private List<RoundModel> lastWinners = new ArrayList<>();
```

RoundModel

```
@Root(name = "ROUND", strict = false)
public class RoundModel {

    @Attribute(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Attribute(name = "nyxid")
    private long nyxId;

    @Element(required = false)
    private LastWinnerModel lastWinnerModel;
```

and LastWinnerModel

```
public class LastWinnerModel {

    @Attribute(name = "TIMESTAMP")
    private String date;

    @Attribute(name = "CHANNEL")
    private String channel;

    @Attribute(name = "BALANCE")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    @Attribute(name = "WONAMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal wonAmonut;

    @Attribute(name = "BONUSWONAMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal bonusWonAmount;

    @Attribute(name = "SUBSYTEMID")
    private int subsystemId;

    @Attribute(name = "CAT1")
    private int cat1;

    @Attribute(name = "CAT2")
    private int cat2;

    @Attribute(name = "CAT3")
    private int cat3;

    @Attribute(name = "OUTCOME")
    private String outcome;

    @Attribute(name = "CLIENT")
    private String client;

    @Attribute(name = "BETAMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal betAmount;

    @Attribute(name = "BONUSBETAMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal bonusBetAmount;

    @Attribute(name = "BASECURRENCY")
    private String baseCurrency;

    @Attribute(name = "PLAYERINFO")
    private PlayerInfoModel playerInfo;
```

In reposne

```
@Element(required = false)
        private LastWinnerModel lastWinnerModel;
```

is always null although I receive some data from external service. I guess the problem is that LastWinnerModel does not have root or maybe there is sth wrong in my models ? Thanks for any replies.

Comment: What are these Root, Attribute annotations? They look like a JAXB variant to me, like XmlRoot, XmlAttribute, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mention that I am using spring. Root this is annotation from org.simpleframework.xml

Comment: I'm not sure if Simple XML can deserialize to a list, could you try RoundModel[] ?

Comment: Per simple xml documentation, "The Element annotation is used to represent a field or method that appears as an XML element." LastWinnerModel represents more than 1 field. So I suggest to inline the LastWinnerModel to RoundModel.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your are not using JAXB for XML binding but a similar Framework with similar (but not identical annotations). I can answer only for JAXB, but very probable its the same Problem with your Framework:

Seems, that the nesting of your model does not reflect the nesting in the XML.
In XML the TIMESTAMP tag is a direct child of the ROUND tag, i.e. properly indented your XML is like this:

```
<EVENTSTREAM...
    <ROUND...
        <TIMESTAMP...
```

So JAXB would try to map the TIMESTAMP tag to a variable in the RoundModel class. However, such a variable does not exist, so the XML value for TIMESTAMP will not be mapped into your model at all and lost (same for CHANEL, BALANCE...).

The model you defined would map to an XML of this structure:

```
<EVENTSTREAM ...
    <ROUND...
        <lastWinnerModel...
            <TIMESTAMP...
```

But if you cant change the XML, in JAXB I dont know a really easy way to map your model by just adding another magical annotation. (You could e.g. use a XmlAdapter class for this in JAXB.) So if you are stuck at that XML it would be the simplest way to merge RoundModel and LastWinnerModel into one class.